# How to get valid URL from the string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using NSURLConnection on the application.
To create HTTP connection, I used following code :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL 
                                       URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain.com/path/sample.php?id=emailaddress@mail.com"]                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                     timeoutInterval:45];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                                 delegate:self];
```

But it throws some exception for this request on the console:

```
Connection failed! Error - bad URL (null)
```

So, I've put the URL on address field of Safari. Safari fixed URL to :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/path/sample.php?id=%1B%1Bemailaddress@mail.com
```

How to correct the URL like Safari ?

Is there an API methods related this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the -stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method on NSString before passing it to NSURL. You should be able to pass NSASCIIStringEncoding for what you're doing.